# Having a difficult time reading a certain Binary file with Python

Tags: python, binaryfiles

I am working on a mod for a game and all of the games strings are in a file called a .dat file. Its a binary file and I'm pretty sure I am missing quite a few strings that I need to add. I have a way to add them into the file I just don't have a way to search for every instance of a missing string. So I decided to write a program to find the missing strings for me. The only problem is I don't know how to open a binary file. Can anyone help me out here. I've included the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/15V7gL-yQ9Na9tcf_yRX9OAFWakPL6l8E/view?usp=sharing) I'm using and a [link](http://www.petrolution.net/item-172) to the .dat editor just in case you want so see what the end result is.

Ive tried to open a binary file the way that others have explained using

```
with open(dat_file_location, mode='rb') as file:
    fileContent = file.read()
    print(fileContent)
```

but all I get back in my terminal are hundreds of lines that look like this

```
00d\x00a\x00r\x00k\x00 \x00m\x00i\x00n\x00e\x00s\x00,\x00 \x00w\x00h\x00e\x00r\x00e\x00
```

Comment: the content of the file seems to be utf-16 encoded text, have you tried to open it in text mode?

Comment: Yes, its still gibberish

Answer (score 0):

Since it's binary you need to know exact format of data. Looking at file I see there is some header and then at offset `0x0038790` string block begins.
Google for `<game title> file format` to get idea how to properly parse it or reverse engineer it yourself ([there is guide how to](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/reverse-engineering-the-binary-data-format-for-star-wars-yoda-stories) do it for another game). btw I think distributing game data files this way is illegal :)

---

from site you linked we can read that [*.DAT- Language files. All text in the game is defined here. Similar to Command and Conquer Generals csf file.](https://www.petrolution.net/item-217?addview)
Probably there is description of file format somewhere on another page

Comment: Even if the game files have been released?

Comment: @BrysonCotton idk, I didn't read exact license, but probably it is.

Comment: @BrysonCotton see upd.

Comment: https://modenc.renegadeprojects.com/CSF_File_Format